# MMS Streaming in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, streaming, iphone-sdk-3.1, mms

hope you all are fine and also in one of your best of moods!!

I have a query to ask you.

I have few mms at server side. I want to stream those mms clips and want to open in my Application.

anybody has any idea how to do this??

kindly share your knowledge...

Looking forwards!!

Regards,

Arun Thakkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either open your MMS url directly in a `UIWebView` or in a `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Properly encode your MMS file, so that can be played in iPhone.
e.g. http://ec2-174-129-153-104.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1935/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8

Comment: Thanks Ruchir, I followed your suggestion but the issue comes when there is a file of extension type which is not supported by iPhone.

for Example clip of type .wmv or else.. Then What is the Solution for this issue?

Comment: You will need to re-encode the video to a format supported by the iPhone, in order for that video to playback with decent performance.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but i am nill in this case, do you have any idea or any Example code from Which i can learn how to re-encode the video format.

looking forwards.

Thanking you,