# mms video streaming on iPhone? (Microsoft Media Server)

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mms

So the question is in title. I almost sure that the answer is NO, but maybe there are some stream converters exist or any other way???

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226842/mms-streaming-in-iphone-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/